# Scrapy: scraping multiple data

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I'm scraping a data from 
`https://www.healthcaresource.com/hhcs/index.cfm?fuseaction=search.jobDetails&template=dsp_job_details.cfm&cJobId=149237` 
but I always get this multiple data being scraped

```
Phillips Barber Family Health Center,Part-time,Day shift,8 Hrs a week/ Sunday- Saturday with Evening Rotation,- Licensure Required,,
```

I only wanted to get the `Phillips Barber Family Health Center` 
what should I do?
I planned of using temp2 = re.search("'^.*?(?=,)'", link).group(1)
but this gives me an error..

Comment: You will have to include your code for us to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by doing

```
["code"] = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()[0].strip()
```